How do I call a program and hand it arguments when a post event occurs?
In keeping with the KISS principal, minimalism, I've got some powerful server side code I'd like to bring to bear on user input in an efficient manner and this question is about how to "release the hounds!" at an efficient moment - that is, when a user has performed a post.
A question I am NOT asking now regarding what I'd like to be doing is have keyword=value pairs derived from a form put into a file, then tell some purely not-web-server-related code to act on that data when the user has posted it. However, that's for another post. For now, I've got a rather simplistic start based on, roughly, this example, as my strongest (but not very strong) web-front-end skills are in PHP and JS / HTTP/CSS - VASTLY stronger in the database-world!
Eventually I'll do this in a more comprehensive form of keyword/value pairs in a file unique to each user interaction, in which case I'd like to hand the called code a unique file name to this ready-to-respond server-side program, I just don't know how to tell it it's time, or hand it the argument of the unique filename.
I'm sure I can get this to work with some clumsy tail -f type affair if it's one file I know the name of, but I'm thinking there MUST be an easier / better way!
To clarify: How do I call an outside program upon a post event and hand it what one might think of as "command line arguments" such as a filename?
In response to comments below: "Does the other program process just this one set of data and then exit?"
I already have a substantial toolset that permits web page creation, editorial review, edits, and more based on EMAIL; I'm now looking to move some of that functionality, and add new functionality, directly from the web interface itself. So, there's no simple answer here.
Likewise, the time it takes and user expectations are all unspecified ATM. Nor are these real concerns. But that they know a submission was made is of course a good design feature, if that's easily done.

It's not clear at all what kind of problem you're trying to solve. Are you looking for shell_exec? Are you looking for FastCGI? What does tail -f have to do with anything?

Note, you should edit your original question to add the additional data instead of posting the same question again. The simple mechanism is just shell_exec() or one of its brethren like exec(), passthru(), popen(). But that's rarely (i.e., never) the best way to do it. Does the other program process just this one set of data and then exit? If so, how long does this process take? Does the person submitting the page need to see any output of the program, or otherwise know what has become of their submission?

@AlexHowansky I tried that and found it was closed while I was busy on the phone... I guess I can't make some people happy! I DID try and update the original question but being closed it appeared to have no effect... I think it was closed FAR too quickly, but that's just me! Here were are. Isn't this OK?

@AlexHowansky As to your comments that address the question, I'll perhaps update the question in a few moments...

This program you're trying to launch -- does it actually exist? Or is it something that you're planning on writing?

@AlexHowansky It's been "in production" over 10 years... It's the foundation of quite a few web sites; a community of authorized users can self-manage their own web site development with editors and content developers cooperating via email, largely based on templates...

Ok so then I don't understand how you can't answer the questions, "Does it exit?" or "How long does it take?" How do you launch this existing tool now? Does it run, and do its thing, and then return to the command line?

@AlexHowansky ?? The new interface is as yet unknown / unknowable; the intent is to take code that's already extant and repurpose / update. ... I don't yet know to just what tasks it will be applied and therefore didn't feel I could answer your questions competently. ... It's NOW launched via email, as I already said... It never returns to the command line because it isn't initiated from teh command line; the inbound email gets sent to a script that analyzes, THEN creates a processing stream and a "grid processing system" performs its many steps...

It sounds like one way to "release the hounds" would be to send an email to your "server" based on the posted data ... assuming this program already works (which you say it does) and it is accessed (or initiated, or called, whatever the right word is) via sending emails.

@topsail Yes, that's it. A loosely associated group of people, some writers, some editors, some other contributors, all collaborate via email. The emails are sent to an email server, the emails are analyzed for authentication and priviliges / permissions / roles and some web pages get created, evaluated, posted, updated and so on. Think of it as a newspaper like  NYT  in the hands of every-day people, mostly all volunteer...

@topsail OH, you edited while I was responding: NO! THIS effort is to change it from being purely email based to having web interaction input as well. And all this has NOTHING to do directly with the question, by the way! ;-)

Do you have something like procmail intercepting delivery and sending individual message contents to this program, one at a time, to be processed? Or is there one process that runs continuously in the background and reads mail folders? Or maybe one process that gets run intermittently via cron?

if you intend to not use emails as the mechanism for running your code ... well, there is no single answer. Usually a web server is able to process input and call code because that's what web servers do. But if your existing code is only invoked through emails, you will have to get into the details of how that works and whether it should be used (in some modified form) or re-factored completely (for instance, to give it a web api interface or simple handle post events from web forms).

@AlexHowansky ... I suppose you don't manage servers? ... In either /etc/aliases or a user's .forward you direct the mail at a script, the script parses, and then calls a program with the results. That program then, with valid input, calls a grid-computing (like cloud computing but local-only) process that then connects to an entire computing engine that evaluates and acts on the request, returning emails, creating or updating web pages as appropriate...

@topsail When you write "Yes, per what Alex Howansky said - exactly how does your program handle incoming mail. The answers lie in the details." I STRONGLY disagree: I'm just looking to how I can efficiently trip the compute engine the way an inbound email does. It might lie dormant for months or seconds, who knows? Polling is not appropriate...

@topsail ... If you're SERIOUSLY interested that deep THEN, the question should be seriously updated / replace to ask things I have yet to get to such as how I know who it is I'm getting input from, and much more - back to that keyword=value business and much more. But I was schooled: keep it short and simple! -ugh!-

@topsail ...Obviously it's just a program that can have arguments passed and obviously I can hack on whatever the arguments are / will do, etc, etc: I propose that you make an answer with all the various options you reasonably see ahead; that not only helps me but also others, the whole point of this community! I don't feel it's terribly pertinent what the responding code does; the context of the situation is fairly clear, from a web user's actions, how can I initiate a program and pass arguments? Is that not answerable?

"I thought you didn't feel that was likely a good answer" That's correct -- I don't feel it's a good answer, but I can't give a better one if you don't answer my questions.

@topsail Thank you, Sir, for your concern for my time. Given I wrote all the code thus far, and don't mind writing more to "do it correctly," if it's not unreasonable to ask, please create an answer with rational options based on what you know so far. I'll be delighted to take it from there. ... Unlike most, I am NOT constrained by anything but the length of my life... ;-)

@AlexHowansky What have I as yet not answered? I'm pretty sure I answered all of them by now?!

"you direct the mail at a script, the script parses, and then calls a program with the results." Does that called program start, process the input for just that one email message, and then exit? Or is it continually running in the background and waiting for connections? If the former, how long does it take to process that one message?

@AlexHowansky The only always-running components there are the email server and a part of the grid-computing system (local-only "cloud computing") known as a "DemandEngine". The email server finds the directive to pass email to a script when it's trying to figure out what mail box to deliver to - this can be in /etc/aliases or in a user's .forward file. When the script receives the email, it's only live for the duration of the parsing and if it finds a reasonably framed input, it makes a database insert, effectively hading it to grid computing, siting idly, waiting...

"it makes a database insert" Well here's some pertinent new information, why not just make this insert from the PHP form submit page?

Aha we have a database!

@AlexHowansky ... Because I didn't know that was reasonably possible?! It's a Postgres database and making DB connections is notoriously problematic and so I hadn't considered it from such a simplistic platform. There's SO much involved - ugh! For one thing the server is, for damned good security reasons NOT on the web server, and second, you must have a fully encrypted RDBMS connection, etc, etc.  ... But just handing the data to a program ready to do that is relatively trivial.

Oh dear. We are back to square one. See comments #1 and #2 ...

"Because I didn't know that was reasonably possible?" This is why we pry for details.  This is like five lines of code.

@topsail In the words of one of my friends, "you funny!" ;-) ... Look, for all your interest in what happens later, just a simple shell script trips off a mountain of work when an email comes in and that's all that's needed here: Just kick a shell script off from a user's post and it's happening... It may or may not be the most efficient but it's not going to be terrible because this isn't a high-frequency event.

@AlexHowansky I'm all ears, Alex!

@AlexHowansky This is the connection URL that the email system uses: jdbc:postgresql://:5432/?=ssl=true&sslmode=require&sslfactory=org.postgresql.ssl.NonValidatingFactory  ... If php can do that?! WOW! And of course, the system and db name cannot be IN THE CODE available to web browsers or search engines!

PHP has had Postgres support since 1996. See here for a good tutorial on the preferred mechanism, PDO. If you're using self-signed certs, you might need some config shenanigans.

@AlexHowansky ,,,In 1995, I was working for Stonebraker literally in the very halls where Postgres was being moved to a fully open-source license, and many on that team were a part of my team as well... (We created the world's first grid computing system that later evolved into "cloud computing," Yet, I wasn't a "front end kinda guy," so I've been ignorant about a lot of this web interface stuff. Thanks for educating me... I'll be looking into this, but ATM I have a guest arriving. ... Much appreciated, Richard.

If you want the simplest, quickest method, just use whichever of exec(), shell_exec(), passthru(), or system() work for you. They all do basically the same thing in slightly different manners. Just run the external program's command line, same as you do from your procmail processing script. PHP will run it, wait for it to finish, and then resume processing. Note, the web user will see a spinning page until the external processing is complete, which may not be desirable if this is a long time. (This is why I kept asking about how long it takes.)
This process will get you your desired result in a very easy, but probably insecure manner. To mitigate security issues, be sure to make use of escapeshellarg() or escapeshellcmd() as appropriate. You will also need to be mindful of permissions, as the external program will need to be executable by the user that runs the PHP process.
A better, faster, more secure solution would be to skip the external program completely. Never use shell_exec() if you don't have to, it should be a last resort. Instead use PHP to directly insert rows into your Postgres database. You could use either PHP's native Postgres driver or the PDO abstraction layer. This site has a good tutorial on the latter.
If you're using self-signed certs, you might need to fiddle with your connect string and/or cert files.
Doing this within PHP will take a tiny fraction of a second, and can be done real-time as the web user waits for their result page to render. You could even give them the post-insert row id as output, like, "Your submission was successful, your job number is #XYZ."
